# How to Control "New Construction" View Created by BIM 360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

[Forge Viewer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAgvv.png)

Hello, I have a question about the "New Construction" view that BIM 360 or the Forge Viewer seem to automatically make. Am I able to control this view somehow in Revit and whehther or not it shows up in BIM 360? Am I also able to control what this view shows or does it just show everything by default?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "New Construction" view could be related to the `generateMasterViews` translation option (in https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#body-structure, go to *Attributes by Output Type*, *SVF Output*, and expand the *advanced* list). With `generateMasterViews` set to `true` (only applicable to Revit inputs) the translation will generate additional views for each "phase" of the Revit model, so I'm wondering if "New Construction" could be a name of a phase.